# filesystem browser for eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

What do you use to explore/browse files with Eclipse?

Answer (score 3):

Go to "Window" > "Open Perspective" > "Remote System". This will show all nodes on your network, including your local machine (`Local`). You can then browse the directories from the `Local` node. More information [here](http://www.venukb.com/2007/06/06/how-to-browse-remote-files-in-eclipse-ide/).

Comment: or add "Remote System" to your current perspective.

Answer (score 1):

I use the Easy Explore plugin which is just great for what you're talking about:
http://easystruts.sourceforge.net/#easyexplore